# how to edit the output of price in woocommerce/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Like the title says I want to get rid of the decimals after my price.

It now looks like this **8.00** but it should be **8**.

i tried trim() and substr($price_html,1,1) but nothing happened

**my code:**

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
            <span class="price">PREIS:<span class="amount">
<?php echo $price_html; ?></span></span><p class="stock-m13"><?php echo $product->get_stock_quantity(); ?>stk.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

any ideas how I can cut of the .00 from the price output(js? manipulate the mysqli query?)

EDIT: i dont have the option "remove zeros" in my wp/woocommerce backend(for those who will ask)

**SOLUTION from danyo:**

```
$price_html = $product->get_price_html();
$new_price = preg_replace('/.00/', '', $price_html);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto WooCommerce Settings, scroll down to Pricing Options and then check the option "Trailing Zeros".

This will then remove the trailing zeros.

**EDIT**

As you dont have this option for some reason you can try this:

```
$price_html = $product->get_price_html();
$new_price = preg_replace('/.00/', '', $price_html);
```

Comment: please read my edit. i dont have this option in my woocomerce settings page

Comment: why is this? do you have the option number of decimal places?

Comment: @danyo can we do it via functions?

Comment: Regex is incorrect, say you have $2,000.00 as input, it will return $20.  Should be: $new_price = preg_replace('/\.00/', '', $price_html); Escaping the decimal. You'll now get $2,000 as expected. Hope this helps someone else using this answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
substr($price_html,0,-3)
```

Comment: thx for your try but that just screws up my layout and the ".00" is still there :(

Answer (score 0):

Use floatval function

```
echo floatval('8.00');
// 125
```

or use 8.00 + 0
// 8

Comment: when i put my variable in there i get a "0" 
<?php echo floatval($price_html); ?>

Comment: $val = "8.00";
echo floatval($val); i tested with this code. is $price_html a string or a object or array value? floatval() will not work with objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get this to work:

```
$price_html = $product->get_price_html();
$new_price = preg_replace('/.00/', '', $price_html);
```

But since I am a newbie to PHP, could someone please give me the exakt code how to use it?